# Rails: How to log an object that might be nil?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the shortest code to log `myvar`, knowing it can be `nil`?

Hopefully something shorter than this:

```
if (myvar==nil)
  logger.debug "myvar is nil"
else
  logger.debug "myvar is " + @myvar.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
logger.debug "myvar is: " + myvar.inspect
```

Comment: It would seem this is the cleanest, clearest and shortest approach.. doh! A real `nil` would display as `nil`; a string "nil" would display as `\"nil\"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
logger.debug "myvar is #{myvar.nil? ? 'nil' : myvar_to_s}"
```

Using `#{...}` inside of double quotes tells Ruby to evaluate the inside of the `{...}` as though it were normal Ruby code.

The `myvar.nil? ? 'nil' : myvar_to_s` portion first calls the `nil?` method on `myvar`. If it returns `true`, the string `'nil'` is used. Otherwise, the value of `myvar.to_s` is used.